# How to access Todoist using Delphi REST?

Tags: delphi, curl

I am trying to access Todoist using Delphi and the REST library, but I don't understand how I can code this:

```
curl https://api.todoist.com/sync/v9/sync \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567" \
    -d sync_token=* \
    -d resource_types='["projects"]'
```

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 Strtoken : string;
 yesplease:boolean;
begin
Strtoken:='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

(* RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'https://api.todoist.com/sync/v9/syn';  *)
RESTRequest1.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET;
RESTRequest1.Accept := 'application/json';
yesplease:=TRUE;
RESTRequest1.Params.Clear;
with RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem do
begin
  Name := 'X-Authorization'; // 'Authorization'
  Value := 'Bearer "'+Strtoken+'"';
  Kind := pkHTTPHEADER;
end;
memo1.Lines.Clear;
memo1.Lines.Add(RestRequest1.GetFullRequestURL(yesplease));

RESTRequest1.Execute;

end;
```

I have tried using the REST Debugger, which I have used before, but I just don't get anywhere (I think I am specifying the parameters incorrectly).

I know the command works, as I have executed it with my token on a Linux box (the one above is an example) and get results.

I've now added my current code - this doesn't seem to want to connect at all and I get various errors from a 404 error, and if I set SSL to true on the RESTClient1 I get different errors.

I want to return the results into a JSON array so I can then process it.

Comment: Maybe show what you've tried?

Comment: You have to make sure that the header item containing the Auth token is not encoded.
I always use AddItem like this -> RESTRequest1.AddItem('Authorization', 'Bearer ' +Strtoken, pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]); Notice the [poDoNotEncode] at the end there.

Comment: Thanks - I am now getting...  Project todoist.exe raised exception class ENetHTTPClientException with message 'Error sending data: (12175) A security error occurred'.  If I tick all the SSL protocols I get a 404 not found...?

Comment: I found an issue with the URL in the component - hence the 404... and also found a useful piece of information https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/4834-how-to-convert-curl-command-line-to-delphi-code-using-indyhttp-or-thttpclient/  - so that instead of adding parameters it should be an Auth method!

Answer (score 2):

There was a typo on the component url - hence the 404!
And also needed to add an Oauth2 component to the page to pass the authentication method..